# Place a wide-table using sagej.cls in a document

Tags: tables, longtable

I am so desperate that I cannot place a table where I want it to be in a two-column document using the document class provided by Sagepub (https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_0.zip).

I want to place a horizontally-centered wide table somewhere in the document. When I use the float package with option [H] the table just disappears.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\def\volumeyear{2015}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\runninghead{Smith and Wittkopf}

\title{A demonstration of the \LaTeXe\ class file for
\itshape{SAGE Publications}}

\author{Alistair Smith\affilnum{1} and Hendrik Wittkopf\affilnum{2}}

\affiliation{\affilnum{1}Sunrise Setting Ltd, UK\\
\affilnum{2}SAGE Publications Ltd, UK}

\corrauth{Alistair Smith, Sunrise Setting Ltd
Torbay Innovation Centre,
 Vantage Point, Long Road,
 Paignton, Devon,
 TQ4~7EJ, UK.}

\email{alistair.smith@sunrise-setting.co.uk}

\begin{abstract}
 This paper describes the use of the \LaTeXe\
\textsf{\journalclass} class file for setting papers to be
 submitted to a \textit{SAGE Publications} journal.
 The template can be downloaded     \href{http://www.uk.sagepub.com/repository/binaries/SAGE LaTeX template.zip}{here}.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Class file, \LaTeXe, \textit{SAGE Publications}}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

 I want the table to appear here.

\begin{table*}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
  \toprule
  & $z_{6}$ & $z_{8}$ & $z_{9}$ & $z_{11}$ & $z_{13}$ & $z_{14}$ \\
  \midrule
  fileA & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.79 & 0.08  \\
  fileB & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.84 & 0.00  \\
  fileC & 0.00 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.49 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  fileD & 0.75 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}
\caption{tabular*}
\end{table*}


 Many authors submitting to research journals use \LaTeXe\ to
 prepare their papers. This paper describes the
\textsf{\journalclass} class file which can be used to convert
 articles produced with other \LaTeXe\ class files into the correct
 form for submission to \textit{SAGE Publications}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: huh, how embarrassed ... I will erase my comment. I apology to OP .

Comment: Your problem is not specific to used document class but to float`figure*`. It can appear only on the top (`[t]`) or bottom (`[b]`) on the *next* page from table inserted point. So the position `H` specifier only confuse LaTeX ... and consequently float disappear. Shortly, your wish seems to be impossible to comply.

Answer (score 1):

As @Zarko has stated, this is a general restriction of page-wide floats in `\twocolumn` documents. However, in this very special case where the table is at the very beginning of the paper you can get the table on the desired place by including the whole onecolumn stuff as an optional argument to the `\twocolumn` command.

```
\twocolumn[%
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
  \toprule
  & $z_{6}$ & $z_{8}$ & $z_{9}$ & $z_{11}$ & $z_{13}$ & $z_{14}$ \\
  \midrule
  fileA & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.79 & 0.08  \\
  fileB & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.84 & 0.00  \\
  fileC & 0.00 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.49 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  fileD & 0.75 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}
\captionsetup{type=table} 
\caption{tabular*}
]
```

The use of the `\caption` command here outside the `table` environment requires the `caption` package, but that is already loaded by the `.cls` file.